# Unity Install Error There is no enough space to download and install the selected items

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 999gb on my new disk and i need 12gb to install unity version and it says
"Theres is no enough space to download and instal the selected items"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N8FS.png)

Comment: Do you really need to install Visual Studio along with Unity? I would always rather install it apart if needed at all and then untick that option

Comment: This thread help? https://forum.unity.com/threads/there-is-not-enough-space-to-download-and-install-the-selected-items-bug.684841/